# For preliminary learning and testing iPhone apps which device to pick if you have to choose from iPhone or ipad iPad2, Is it ok to test it on iPad2?

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS world.

What it seems to me if i buy new iPad2 i can test both iPhone and iPad apps 
According to me there is only major difference in terms of Screen space.

So for preliminary learning and testing is it ok to test it on ipad2.I am looking forward to buy only one iOS 5 device.Is there any better option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either device will be ok for learning. You can even start learning without investing in a device because you can ran the applications you develop on the iOS Simulator which comes with Xcode.

Testing on device is important only if you are developing an actual application, and in this case, you need to test the app on all the devices it will run on: iPhone, iPad or both. So if you have an idea for an app that will target only iPhone or iPad, buy that device now or later.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 3GS will be better option to keep your investment low initially.

From coding point of view first start with iPhone and then once you master it switching to iPad development would be much easier.

For real application it has to be tested on each device on which you are targeted it for.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an iPod touch.  There are missing some of the hardware that an iPhone has, but for basic testing they work well.  And you can get a previous gen version from eBay for only about $100.